# Devise sign in and sign up using single form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm trying to do the following: I have a page with a form for login and password.
Is it possible to use this form for both registration and authorization. For example i'm visiting the page for the first time and enter my email and password. Then if such email already exists i get an error, otherwise an account is created for me. Searching for the way of implementing this gave no results.
Does anyone know hot to make it possible?

Comment: Sure it is possible.  Just in your code when you make the database hit to see if the email exists, add the logic that says if it doesn't exist then do an insert in to the database.     I'm not a ruby guy so I can't give you the actual code example but if you can find the example of how to do the insert then

Answer (score -1):

This approach has one drawback: If user mistyped password then he would probably never login again. Solution - to use email for password recovery.

Other approach is to let user input email and while user will type password check if email is already in database. If it's not available then add password confirmation field to the form.

How to make it possible? Just program the necessary logic on server-side and client-side.

Comment: But the form contains an action of either of registrations controller or sessions controller and i don't want to write my own registration or session creation logic.

`action=/accounts/login`

note that devise default routes are changed to custom ones.